# correct positioning with Highcharts renderer on a bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) bar chart that I'm trying to add custom shapes to based on the bar values and position. To start with, I'm just trying to use  [highcharts.renderer.path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path()), to add a line for each bar, as tall as the bar, positioned on the x axis based on a hard coded value. Here's a picture of what I mean:

[image: example bar chart]

This should be easy, and it is when the chart.type = "column". In the highcharts callback, I would use [getBBox()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.getBBox()) on each bar, and [translate()](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=9404) to convert the x axis value to a pixel value.

However, I've run into several problems when trying to do this with chart.type = "bar". First, all x and y values are switched (I assume this is how the author created the bar chart from a column chart in the first place). This is true for all the properties of the chart as well: plotLeft is now the top, plotTop is now the left.

This should work:

```
function (chart) {
    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (pointIndex, point) {
        var plotLine = {},
            elem = point.graphic.element.getBBox(),
            yStart,
            xStart,
            newline;

        yStart = chart.plotTop+elem.x;
        xStart = chart.plotLeft+elem.height;

        plotLine.path = ["M", xStart, yStart+1, "L", xStart, yStart+point.pointWidth];        
        plotLine.attr = {
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: point.color,
            zIndex: 5
        };

        newline = chart.renderer.path(plotLine.path).attr(plotLine.attr).add();
    });        
});
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bh3J4/9/

The second issue may be a bug that can't be overcome. It appears that when there is more than one data point, all of the x and y values get mixed up between the points. Notice in the fiddle that the colors don't match the positions. I've created an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1808).

When there's just one point, it's not a problem. When there are two points, I could easily switch the values to get the right positioning. However when there are 3 or more points, I can't seem to figure out the logic for how the values get mixed up.

The third issue, is that the translate function doesn't seem to work on the xAxis for a bar chart, even though it does on the yAxis.

```
chart.yAxis[0].translate(4); // correct for bottom axis
chart.xAxis[0].translate(1); // incorrect for side axis
```

Is there another way to achieve what I'm looking for? Am I missing something in that Fiddle that's not actually a bug?

Comment: @zacarybrown discovered that at least the x values of getBBox() are reversed for bar charts: https://twitter.com/zacarybrown/status/332121728916529153

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the result I wanted, but I don't know if it's coincidental or a workaround for an actual bug. Regardless, it seems that using the x value from the reverse sorted array helped me line everything up correctly. Here's the callback function for highcharts:

```
function (chart) {
    var benchmarks = { A: 1.5, B: 3.6, C: 2 },
        reverseData = _.clone(chart.series[0].data).reverse();

    _.each(chart.series[0].data, function (point, pointIndex) {
        var plotLine = {},
            elem = point.graphic.element.getBBox(),
            reverseElem = reverseData[pointIndex].graphic.element.getBBox(),
            benchmark = benchmarks[point.category],
            yStart = chart.plotTop+reverseElem.x,
            xStart = chart.plotLeft+chart.yAxis[0].translate(benchmark),
            yEnd = yStart+point.pointWidth-1;

        plotLine.path = ["M", xStart, yStart+1, "L", xStart, yEnd];        
        plotLine.attr = {
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: "red",
            zIndex: 5
        };        
        chart.renderer.path(plotLine.path).attr(plotLine.attr).add();

        var margin = 5,
            xPadding = 10,
            yPadding = 5,
            xSplit = xPadding/2,
            ySplit = yPadding/2,
            text,
            box;

        text = chart.renderer.text("Top Perf Avg " + benchmark, xStart, yEnd+margin+16).attr({
            color: "#646c79",
            align: "center", 
            "font-family": "Arial, sans-serif",
            "font-size": 9,
            "font-weight": "bold",
            style: "text-transform: uppercase",
            zIndex: 7
        }).add();
        box = text.getBBox();
        chart.renderer.path(["M", box.x-xSplit, box.y-ySplit, 
                             "l", (box.width/2)+xSplit-margin, 0, 
                             margin, -margin, 
                             margin, margin, 
                             (box.width/2)+xSplit-margin, 0,
                             0, box.height+yPadding, 
                             -(box.width+xPadding), 0,
                             0, -(box.height+yPadding)])
                             .attr({
                                'stroke-width': 1,
                                stroke: "#cccccc",
                                fill: "#ffffff",
                                zIndex: 6
        }).add();

    });

}
```

See the complete working graph here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bh3J4/18/

Answer (score 0):

In the fact, Highcharts rotate everything using `transform`, so use the same to rotate these lines, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bh3J4/19/

```
function (chart) {
var d = chart.series[0].data,
    len = d.length;
for(var i =0; i < len; i++){

    var point = d[i],
        plotLine = {},
        elem = point.graphic.element.getBBox(),
        yStart,
        xStart,
        newline;
    console.log(point,point.color);
    xStart = point.plotX - point.pointWidth / 2;
    yStart = point.plotY;

    plotLine.path = ["M", xStart, yStart, "L", xStart+point.pointWidth, yStart];        
    plotLine.attr = {
        transform: 'translate(491,518) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        stroke: point.color,
        zIndex: 5
    };

    newline = chart.renderer.path(plotLine.path).attr(plotLine.attr).add();
};
}
```

Comment: That's definitely closer, but do you think you could edit your fiddle so that the color matched paths line up exactly with the bars (and at the end of them)?

Answer (score 0):

Slight adjustment that seems to give precise alignment:

Pls note: changes to calc of xStart/yStart and change to transform translate parameter.
My approach was to make it work for column chart and then get translate refined.
The only unsatisfactory part is that xStart needs: `xStart = elem.x+chart.plotLeft;` in 'column' mode vs `xStart = elem.x;` in 'bar' mode...

```
function (chart) {
var d = chart.series[0].data,
    len = d.length;
for(var i =0; i < len; i++){

    var point = d[i],
        plotLine = {},
        elem = point.graphic.element.getBBox(),
        yStart,
        xStart,
        newline;
    console.log(point,point.color);
    xStart = elem.x;
    yStart = chart.plotHeight - (elem.height/2) + chart.plotTop;

    plotLine.path = ["M", xStart, yStart, "L", xStart+point.pointWidth, yStart];        
    plotLine.attr = {
        transform: 'translate(542.5,518) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)',
        'stroke-width': 5,
        stroke: 'blue',
        zIndex: 5
    };

    newline = chart.renderer.path(plotLine.path).attr(plotLine.attr).add();
};
}
```